# Any music player whose library only searches for (.m3u) playlist files and can exclude subfolders?

Tags: playlists, audio-player, media-library

I'm one of those maniacs who want their music library presented exactly as they want it. :)

I've tried several players (Clementine, Audacious, Amarok, gmusicbrowser, Guayadeque, Nightingale, QMMP, Lollypop, Quod Libet, Rythmbox) but couldn't find a way to achieve these two goals:

1/ In a main /MUSIC/ folder, I have a subfolder per album. But also a few subfolders that I want to exlude from the player's library.

2/ In each album subfolder lies a .m3u file. I'd like the library to consider the contents of this file as an album. (The goal is to prevent the library from browsing say, a compilation album by several artists, and displaying all these artists separately. Maybe there are other solutions to this than looking for .m3u files.)

Back in my Windows days, the [album list plugin for Winamp](http://albumlist.sourceforge.net/) did exactly what I'm looking for today.

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to point 1/:

In gmusicbrowser's configuration (using version 1.1.15), at the bottom of the Library tab, it's possible to define a custom main filter, requiring that some Folders don't contain a certain text. I was able to exclude several subfolders in my main music folder this way.